# teechart delphi reportbuilder limit data from pipeline

Tags: delphi, teechart, reportbuilder

I have my teechart data series using a data pipeline as my source.  The table that I have as my datasource has 60 rows of data but I only want to graph based on 3 of those rows.  The data for the other 57 rows is 0 for the columns that I am graphing on.  The graph that I want (based on 3 rows) would show 6 large bars  ( 2 columns x 3 rows ) but since the series has 57 unused and unseen rows, the 6 bars are very thin.  How can I limit the data from the data source to just 3 rows?

The following images show the result I want (6 large bars) versus what I am getting (6 thin bars).

[image: Graph 1]

[image: Graph 2]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Provide some code samples you have tried, so that people can point you in the right direction. Good luck.

Comment: Hi there.  I am trying to do this using the reportbuilder RAP and DADE so I don't have any code samples.  I have tried to chart1.series[0].add ( 100, "") but that will not compile (in an attempt to manually add data).  The results shown above simply are using the edit chart interface so there is no code.

Comment: Why don't you filter your dataset down to the six rows you want?

Answer (score 1):

As [@John Easley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1120271/john-easley) says in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51365043/teechart-delphi-reportbuilder-limit-data-from-pipeline#comment89710461_51365043), instead of assigning the table to the series, you could filter it.

Ie, using the "Employee" table from the "TeeChart Pro Database", shipped with TeeChart components. Here the full data:

[image: Full data]

You could loop that table and use `Add`/`AddXY` to add the values approved by a condition to your series:

```
uses Series;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with Chart1.AddSeries(TBarSeries) do
  begin
    Marks.Style:=smsValue;

    Table1.Open;
    while not Table1.Eof do
    begin
      if Table1.FieldByName('SALARY').AsFloat > 42000 then
         Add(Table1.FieldByName('SALARY').AsFloat, Table1.FieldByName('LASTNAME').AsString);

      Table1.Next;
    end;
    Table1.Close;
  end;
end;
```

[image: Filtered]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers.

Because I am using ReportBuilder and RAP I had to do it slightly differently but the concept was the same.

In my report template I created a Teechart set to manual data.  Then I used the following code to Add XY points:

`ChartManual.chart.series[0].clear;
ChartManual.chart.series[0].AddXY(1,100,'A',RGB(0,0,252));
ChartManual.chart.series[0].AddXY(2,200,'B',RGB(0,0,252));
...etc`

Finding the exact RAP syntax was a bit tough so I hope this can help others in this situation.

Thanks again

J